# Dynamically Create Functions with Eval() in PHP

Tags: php, function, syntax, eval

I'm trying to create functions dynamically with `eval()`. But I get this warning: `Notice: Use of undefined constant` Any suggestion?

```
$funcs = array('func_a', 'func_b', 'func_c');
foreach($funcs as $func_name) {
    eval( 'function ' . $func_name . '() { 
            mainfunc(' . $func_name . '); 
        }' 
    );  
}

func_a();
func_b();
func_c();

function mainfunc($func_name) {
    echo $func_name . '<br />';
}
```

Assuming the array `$func` is an option value stored in a database and I need the function names for  a callback function in a separate part of the script. So creating anonymous functions with `create_function()` is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your info.

Comment: In the line `mainfunc(' . $func_name . ');`, you need to wrap `$func_name` in quotes. As it stands now, that line turns to `mainfunc(func_a);`.

Comment: This seems like a pretty bad idea overall. Just saying.

Comment: take a look over here also; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438521/call-a-function-without-knowing-its-name/

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to create function dynamically in such case.

Comment: To those who don't see the necessity of it, there are cases which need to pass function names to a custom function which expects a function name in the parameter as a call-back function, like `add_action()` in WordPress. When creating action hooks to schedule background processes in WordPress based on unique Ids, creating dynamic functions based on the saved ID becomes useful. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I do not have too much experience with Wordpress, but I know that at least some things in Wordpress accept other things than pure strings. I.e., any valid callback in PHP should work, like `array($obj, 'method')`. Also, if you use `create_function`, this will work as well, since it creates an actual function with a random name, the name of which you can pass around!

Comment: You would have to be more detailed about what exactly you are doing, but I'm sure there's a better approach than `eval`, such as an object or class callback (`array($objectorclassname, $methodname)`) , using a function with arguments (the `$accepted_args` parameter of `add_action()`), using an anonymous function (PHP 5.3+), etc.

Comment: @deceze I'll see if `add_action()` accepts an object method and the thing is that I need to pass the task name (I said ID in the previous comment). `add_action()` seems to accept arguments but I have to test if the arguments get overwitten when the same method/function name is used multiple times with different arguments. And I don't think `create_function()` would work in my case because it need to be a solid function name to be registered.

Comment: @FrancisAvila If I go in details, it will become a really long story for you to digest what I'm trying to do. It's actually a continuation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354873/renew-wordpress-feed-cache-in-the-background Thanks for your input. I'll see if I can avoid using `eval()`

Comment: Functions created with `create_function` are not any more or less "solid" than "real" functions! :)

Comment: The problem is that WordPress doesn't remember the registered action name in the previous page load or in the next page load. So the name has to be static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your eval body needs to read:

```
mainfunc(\'' . $func_name . '\');
```

Without the single quotes, eval() makes code that has an unquoted literal--an undefined constant.

Answer (score 4):

Use better approach than eval(), it is called [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

Example:

```
class MainFunc {

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        echo "_call($name)<br>";
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        echo "_callStatic($name)<br>";
    }

}

# php >= 5.4.x
(new MainFunc)->func_a();
(new MainFunc)->func_b("param", "param2");
# or php < 5.4
$mainFunc = new MainFunc;
$mainFunc->func_a();
$mainFunc->func_b("param", "param2");

MainFunc::func_a_static();
MainFunc::func_b_static("param", "param2");
```

Output is:

```
_call(func_a)
_call(func_b)
_callStatic(func_a_static)
_callStatic(func_b_static)
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your input. Just my PHP version does not support the `callStack()` method.

Comment: Then do not use __callStatic(). I have just demonstrated both possible solutions.

Comment: `__call()` seems to be the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who were wondering what I was talking about, here is the sample WordPress plugin which demonstrates how dynamic function creation comes handy.

```
/* Plugin Name: Sample Action Hooks with Dynamic Functions */

// assuming this is an option retrieved from the database
$oActions = array(  'a' => array('interval' => 10, 'value' => 'hi'),
                    'b' => array('interval' => 30, 'value' => 'hello'),
                    'c' => array('interval' => 60, 'value' => 'bye')
            );  

add_action('init', LoadEvents);
function LoadEvents() {
    global $oActions;
    foreach($oActions as $strActionName => $array) {
        eval( 'function ' . $strActionName . '() { 
                    SampleEvents(\'' . $strActionName . '\'); 
                }' 
        );  
        add_action('sampletask_' . md5($strActionName), $strActionName);
        if (!wp_next_scheduled( 'sampletask_' . md5($strActionName)))
            wp_schedule_single_event(time() + $oActions[$strActionName]['interval'], 'sampletask_' . md5($strActionName));                  
    }
}
function SampleEvents($strActionName) {
    global $oActions;
    // just log for a demo
    $file = __DIR__ . '/log.html';
    $current = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . ': ' . $strActionName . ', ' . $oActions[$strActionName]['value'] . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND);    
    wp_schedule_single_event(time() + $oActions[$strActionName]['interval'], 'sampletask_' . md5($strActionName));
}
```

And the same functionality could be achieved with `__call()`.

```
/* Plugin Name: Sample Action Hooks */

add_action('init', create_function( '', '$oSampleEvents = new SampleEvents;' ));
class SampleEvents {
    public $oActions = array(   'a' => array('interval' => 10, 'value' => 'hi'),
                                'b' => array('interval' => 30, 'value' => 'hello'),
                                'c' => array('interval' => 60, 'value' => 'bye')
                        );
    function __construct() {                
        foreach($this->oActions as $strActionName => $arrAction) {
            add_action('sampletask_' . md5($strActionName), array(&$this, $strActionName));
            if (!wp_next_scheduled( 'sampletask_' . md5($strActionName)))
                wp_schedule_single_event(time() + $this->oActions[$strActionName]['interval'], 'sampletask_' . md5($strActionName));
        }
    }
    function __call($strMethodName, $arguments) {
        // just log for a demo
        $file = __DIR__ . '/log.html';
        $current = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . ': ' . $strMethodName . ', ' . $this->oActions[$strMethodName]['value'] . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND);    
        wp_schedule_single_event(time() + $this->oActions[$strMethodName]['interval'], 'sampletask_' . md5($strMethodName));
    }
}
```